# How do I get Ubuntu to recognize a newer version of Cogl?

Tags: environment-variables, configure, clutter

I'm trying to install clutter-1.26.0 as a prerequisite for other things. When I run ./configure it gets held up here:

```
configure: error: Package requirements (cogl-1.0 >= 1.21.2 cogl-path-1.0 cairo-gobject >= 1.14.0 gio-2.0 >= 2.44.0 atk >= 2.5.3 pangocairo >= 1.30 cogl-pango-1.0 json-glib-1.0 >= 0.12.0 gdk-3.0 wayland-cursor wayland-client xkbcommon x11 xext xdamage xcomposite >= 0.4 xi) were not met:

Requested 'cogl-1.0 >= 1.21.2' but version of Cogl is 1.16.2
No package 'cogl-path-1.0' found
Requested 'cairo-gobject >= 1.14.0' but version of cairo-gobject is 1.13.1
No package 'cogl-pango-1.0' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables CLUTTER_DEPS_CFLAGS
and CLUTTER_DEPS_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

I have a newer version cogl installed (cogl-1.22.2), but it doesn't seem to recognize it. If I figure this out I assume it will be a similar solution for the cairo-gobject problem.
Do I need to install cogl-1.22.2 in the same directory as clutter-1.26.0? Or how can I get this installer to point to the correct cogl version?

Comment: How exactly did you install the newer versions of cogl and cairo-gobject? What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I installed cogl by downloading the tar.xz from launchpad, unzipping it, and running ./configure, make, make install. I didn't run into any errors installing cogl-1.22.2, but clutter isn't recognizing it.

Comment: Did you specify a `--prefix` directory for the `./configure`? where did the packages actually install to? did they install `.pc` files, and if so is the location of those first on the `pkg-config` search path (`pkg-config --variable pc_path pkg-config`)?

Comment: Thanks for keeping up with my lack of experience :)
I did not use a --prefix. Cogl installed to its own cogl-1.22.2 directory. There are no .pc files in that directory (though possibly in some subdirectories).  And the location does not appear in the pkg-config search path. 
Can I move it into the same directory as clutter-1.26.0? Can I reinstall it into the same directory as clutter? And should/how would I add its path to the pkg-config search path?